# Is there a way to search a menu bar in Debian?

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, gnome3

I want to search my menu bar, to easily find obscure menu items.

I know that the HUD (Heads Up Display) in Unity has this feature, however I am running Gnome 3 on Debian 7.

Is there a way to do this on my system?

Answer (score 0):

[This Web page](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/best-linux-desktop-search-tools) discusses several possibilties, after reading it I moved to *Recoll*. And, while you are at it, but unrelated to the OP, you may also wish to consider *Awesome-wm* as Window Manager.